# How can one read a file from MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file-io, scanf

I have a text file that contains 113 line and 10 columns. Every line has the following format:

```
user1   10137   21  0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

The first field is always a string, the next two fields are integers and last 7 fields are float. I tired the following (and different variations of it).

```
fid = fopen('frames.dat', 'r');
A = fscanf(fid, '%s %u %u %f %f %f %f %f %f %f',[10,113]);
fclose(fid);
```

But it does not work. Can anybody please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the error you're seeing? Or the output?

Comment: I do not see any errors. I just do not get what I expect. For example A(1,1) returns `u` (I think it is a first letter of `user1`). I want to have `user1`  as A(1,1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) in the following way:

```
fid=fopen('frames.dat','r');
A=textscan(fid,'%s %u %u %f %f %f %f %f %f %f');
fclose(fid);
```

Then you would have a cell array A with the first colum as a cell array of strings and the other columns as numeric arrays. You can access a given field with the command `A{column}(row)`.

Comment: not clear from the question, but if the columns are separated by tabs, you could specify that with the `'Delimiter','\t'` property of TEXTSCAN